# Are table-scan results held in memory negating the benefit of indexes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Theoretical SQL Server 2008 question:

If a table-scan is performed on SQL Server with a significant amount of 'free' memory, will the results of that table scan be held in memory, thereby negating the efficiencies that may be introduced by an index on the table?

Update 1: The tables in question contain reference data with approx. 100 - 200 records per table (I do not know the average size of each row), so we are not talking about massive tables here.

I have spoken to the client about introducing a memcached / AppFabric Cache solution for this reference data, however that is out of scope at the moment and they are looking for a 'quick win' that is minimal risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the performance problem (even when all pages are in memory a scan is still going to be many many times slower than an index seek on any table of significant size) there is an additional issue: **contention**.

The problem with scans is that any operation will have to visit *every* row. This means that any select will block behind any insert/update/delete (since is *guaranteed* to visit the row locked by these operations). The effect is basically serialization of operations and adds huge latency, as SELECT now have to wait for DML to *commit* every time. Even under mild concurrency the effect is an overall sluggish and slow to respond table. With indexes present operations are only looking at rows in the ranges of interest and this, by virtue of simple probabilities, reduces the chances of conflict. The result is a much livelier, responsive, low latency system.

Answer (score 6):

Every page read in the scan will be read into the buffer pool and only released under memory pressure as per the cache eviction policy.

Not sure why you think that would negate the efficiencies that may be introduced by an index on the table though.

An index likely means that many fewer pages need to be read and even if all pages are already in cache so no physical reads are required reducing the number of logical reads is a good thing. Logical reads are not free. They still have overhead for locking and reading the pages.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your comment re. fewer page reads when using an index - even if they are from the cache - is the answer I was looking for. N.

Answer (score 1):

Full Table Scans also are not scalable as the data grows.  It’s very simple.  As more data is added to a table, full table scans must process more data to complete and therefore they will take longer.  Also, they will produce more Disk and Memory requests, further putting strain on your equipment. 
Consider a 1,000,000 row table that a full table scan is performed on.  SQL Server reads data in the form of an 8K data page.  Although the amount of data stored within each page can vary, let’s assume that on average 50 rows of data fit in each of these 8K pages for our example.  In order to perform a full scan of the data to read every row, 20,000 disk reads (1,000,000 rows / 50 rows per page).  That would equate to 156MB of data that has to be processed, just for this one query.  Unless you have a really super fast disk subsystem, it might take it a while to retrieve all of that data and process it.  Now then, let’s say assume that this table doubles in size each year.  Next year, the same query must read 312MB of data just to complete.

Pls refer this link - http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/key-sql-performance-situations-full-table-scan

Comment: +1 Good point but [you should quote your source](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/key-sql-performance-situations-full-table-scan)

Comment: Thanks AnandPhadke, it is worth noting that the tables in question hold reference data that is unlikely to grow beyond 100 - 200 records (at the moment I couldn't tell you the average size of each row) and is likely to remain static for (possibly) month's at a time. I have updated my original question to reflect this.